# Using Try/except with a QTimer

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

I use a `QTimer` to start a method, which starts a timer. When I push a `QPushButton` I need to stop this timer and do another things. So, when I push the button i get this error:

`TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not connected`

How can I use a `try-except`method to avoid this error. This is what i´ve done:

```
def delete(self):
    try:
        self.tmr.timeout.disconnect(self.run_save_clock)
        self.tmr.timeout.disconnect(self.append_Data)
        self.data = []
        self.time_label_2.setText("00:00:00")
        self.data_label.setText("000000")

    except "TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not connected": #HERE IS WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM
        self.tmr.timeout.disconnect(self.append_Data)
        self.data = []
        self.time_label_2.setText("00:00:00")
        self.data_label.setText("000000")
```

But it does not works. The `self.data` is a variable where I save some data while the timer is active.

The error appears when I first push another `QPushButton` that is connected to this method:

```
def stop(self):
    self.saveBtn.setEnabled(True)
    self.stopBtn.setEnabled(False)
    self.tmr.timeout.disconnect(self.run_save_clock)
    self.tmr.timeout.disconnect(self.append_Data)
```

What am i doing wrong with the `try/except` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html, you should not include the string error message right after "except" but rather the ErrorType and then add the error message you want raised as follows:

```
try:
    #something

except TypeError:
    #Do something here
    print " 'instancemethod' object is not connected"
    #Or do something here
```